# Cannot get python Turtle to work in Pydev on linux

Tags: python, eclipse, tkinter, pydev, turtle-graphics

I'm running Fedora 17 and I had Eclipse installed. I'm trying to do an assignment that uses python Turtle by importing turtle. I get red flags whenever I use the turtle methods, like `turtle.forward(100)`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g2n/Desktop/school/college/cs/240/src/cw1/faces.py", line 6, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

My `pydev` path is `/usr/local/bin/python3.3`

Anyone help?!

Comment: why do you not use the system python (at `/usr/bin/python3`) ?

Comment: @FabienAndre the system Python will often have the same problem, but requiring a different approach to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other link said, make sure you install `tk-dev` before trying to import the module in python; i would also test this on a Python 2.7 interpreter, 3.3 is too new and Tkinter may not be entirely supported or not well tested. So, if allowed, try 2.7.

Make sure you are importing it correctly: `import Tkinter`

Here's how to install `Tkinter`
http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter

And here's a link that can provide you with some RPMs for Tkinter:
http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=tk-devel

Comment: `tk-dev` is not needed to use tkinter. It is only needed to build another python with tkinter support. And python3.3 is not so new and works (and is tested) perfectly on recent distros.

Comment: I did an install for tk-dev and it didn't work. Importing tkinter also doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check dependencies and all of the needed libraries - Think Python clearly states that.
2. Try to use not a python3.3 but earlier python version 2.7
3. Why do you need eclipse? and what OS you are running?

Comment: #3 , OP stated hes on Fedora 17, but didn't say which arch; 32/64bit?

Comment: My bad (OS...). I think 2.7 will solve his problems.

Comment: What's the difference between 3.3 and 2.7?